# remove uv4l "software by http://linux-project.org" watermark

Tags: raspicam, uv4l, compute-module

Using the Compute Module & IO Board, I installed uv4l. 
I'm just not sure why this "software by http://linux-project.org" watermark showed up only when I use Stereoscopic Vision.

(No watermark when I use Dual Cameras separately: https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/dual-cameras/)

[image]

Is there a way that I could hide/remove the watermark?

Also the stream itself works, but I can't get webrtc to work for dual camera at all.

Comment: try setting –text-annotation-background no and –text-overlay disabled, but sounds like a bug

Comment: According to the developer feedback, "watermark on the compute module can be removed if UV4L is intended to be used commercially"....

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using uv4l's `raspicam` driver to driver the raspberry pi camera, you can use the kernel-based `bcm2835-v4l2` driver. Just `modprobe` it and enable it using `raspi-config`, and you should have a `/dev/video0` file.

After the device file appears, you can start uv4l with these options:

`uv4l --external-driver --device-name=video0`

The text overlay will be gone, and the rest of uv4l's features should work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following in motion.conf and it will be removed:

```
v4l2_palette 8
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me.

Send a mail to **info@linux.org** asking them to remove the watermark stating the reason you are using for (project/thesis/commercial).
They will ask you to mail the output of uv4l driver serial number provided you give credits in which you use it for.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one did provide a step by step solution, let me help you out.

In my case, uv4l installed with a service running at boot. I wrote another service, but a quick and easy way is to edit the service installed by uv4l.

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/uv4l_raspicam.service
```

Now change this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uv4l -f -k --sched-fifo --mem-lock --config-file=/etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf --driver raspicam --driver-config-file=/etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf --server-option=--editable-config-file=/etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf
```

into this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uv4l -f -k --sched-fifo --mem-lock --config-file=/etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf --external-driver --device-name=video0 --server-option=--editable-config-file=/etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf
```

Reload the systemctl daemon:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Restart the service:

```
sudo service uv4l_raspicam restart
```

Check the status:

```
sudo service uv4l_raspicam status
```

Last line should state something similar to:

```
May 13 12:02:00 raspberrypi uv4l[7155]: <notice> [driver] Using video device /dev/video0
```

I hope I helped a lot of you :)

Answer (score -1):

Just use `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` and change the input device to `/dev/video0`.

Comment: This is exactly what the top-voted answer suggests.